# How to export multiple relationships of contact

Tags: export

i am confusing how to show all relationship in the exported report, there's a example below.

Company A have 3 representatives in the relationship field.

and using following method to export.

find membership -> select Company A -> export members -> Select fields for export (Field Mapping).

The exported report show 1 representative of comapny A only. Any advance or solution ?

i have tried multiple columns on Using Field Mapping during "Select fields for export" phase. it doesn't work.

Comment: have you had a look at using the Relationships Report to export?

Comment: Hi petednz, thanks for your reply! Relationships Report show the name of contact A & B and their relationship only. any report can show all the relationship with the name, id, mail...those contact  information ? Thanks.

Comment: sorry but i didn't quite understand your comment. If you are saying 'no that report doesn't help as it doesn't include Custom fields' - you may want to add that requirement in your Subject. 2 other thoughts. Why not do a Search to find the people who are Employed, then export. perhaps that would give you what you need? If you are on Drupal then Views is the other option. If any of this is useful i will convert to an Answer

Comment: My goal is that any report contain contacts information with their all relationship? so that the Relationships Report is not my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Why not do a Search to find the people who are Employed (rather than the employers), then export. perhaps that would give you what you need? since each Employee will only have one Employer (hopefully)